# Sort 2 arrays by the same way

Tags: processing

I have two arrays that are not sorted: a float array (`float[]`), and a *String* array (`String[]`) for the descriptions.

I need to **sort the float array from the highest value to the lowest**, but the descriptions are in the *String* array and if I sort them, the *String* array won't be sorted accordingly.

In *Processing*, there is a [`sort(Array)`](https://processing.org/reference/sort_.html) function, but it only sorts one array.

How can I sort the float array and have the descriptions match?

```
float totalCount = 0;
float maxValue = 0;
String[] statusDescriptions = new String[finishStatusesJSON.size()];
float[] countData = new float[finishStatusesJSON.size()]; 
for (int i = 0; i < finishStatusesJSON.size(); i++) {
  JSONObject finishStatusJSON = (JSONObject) finishStatusesJSON.get(i);
  float count = finishStatusJSON.getFloat("count"); 
  String status = finishStatusJSON.getString("status");
  totalCount += count;
  statusDescriptions[i] = status;
  countData[i] = count;

  // Max value of the table
  if(maxValue < count) maxValue = count;

}
```

Comment: Create a simple class that holds both values and use that in your array

Comment: I wanted to avoid create a lot more code. Is this that hard to achive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Sort one array based on values of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556129/java-sort-one-array-based-on-values-of-another-array)

Comment: @LeoLeontev this is basic java, I can't use that 8 stuff here

Comment: maybe I can use the JSONArray `finishStatusesJSON` to sort?

Comment: you can use a `dictionary` to find the values of `String` array using float values as __key__. The you only need to order float array and get the String values from dictionary (HasMap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use a simple class to hold both pieces of data and keep it in one array for easier sorting. Sorting is supported by implementing the `Comparable` protocol.

```
class Status implements Comparable<Status> {
    String  status;
    float count;

    public Status(String status, float count) {
        this.status = status;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Status s) {        
        if (this.count < s.count) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.count > s.count) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

Status[] statusArray = new Status[finishStatusesJSON.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < finishStatusesJSON.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject finishStatusJSON = (JSONObject) finishStatusesJSON.get(i);
    Status status = new Status(finishStatusJSON.getString("status"), finishStatusJSON.getFloat("count")); 

    statusArray[i] = status;
}

Arrays.sort(statusArray);
```

Comment: This is not sorting!!

Comment: @user10992206, hold on a second I am getting there. I forgot to include it.

Comment: @user10992206, sorting support added

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a class that contains your entries, i.e. that combines a float with its description. For example, if you store movies as strings and their scores as floats, you could create a class `MovieScore` that contains the movie description (the string) and its score (the float). You could make this class `Comparable` and then sort an array of `MovieScore`s to achieve your goal.

Comment: this is not java 8

Comment: @user10992206 This answer works in all versions of Java

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a [`Map<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) type of array, where the `K` would be the [*Float*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) class, while the `V` would be the [*String*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

Thus, you could use the [`put(K,V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) method, like below, and then, sort properly.

```
float count = finishStatusJSON.getFloat("count");
totalCount += count;

map.put( count, finishStatusJSON.getString("status") );
```

Although, it seems like you're talking about Processing, not Java.

---

**Erratum:** It might be better to use a [*SortedMap*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) implementing class; since you would be able to put a [*Comparator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) directly into the constructor, or use the natural ordering, and the *Map* will sort itself.

If you still want to use a *Map* implementing class, then I suggest that you use *Map*'s [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) method, then follow the same algorithm as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391350/how-to-sort-a-hashset).

However, I'm skeptical of using those classes in Processing, since it might be in fact invalid for its framework; but if it compiles and there is no execution error/exception, then it may be worth a try.

Comment: but this is not sorted

Comment: Processing is inspired by Java, but it's still far from Java.

You can't use class (static) methods, for example.

Comment: I have edited my message.

If the classes seem to work, then you should try with a [Comparator<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class which will sort the keys in a decreasing order.