# Sort two arrays "parallel" in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have two Java arrays, "int[] myInt" and "float[] myFloat". Both have the same size and are very large. Array elements of the same index belong together (myInt[42] belongs to myFloat[42] and so on).

My problem: I want to sort the myInt array and "parallel" myFloat, so that the data pairs already are the same after sorting.

I cannot put the pairs into own data objects because the overhead of java objects would crash the memory.

Do you have an idea to use some JVM classes for solving this problem without programming the sort algorithm for my own? Is there any sort algorithm that calls my code and tells me "change your data own index x and y" or anything like this?

Thanks for any help!

Here an example:

```
int[] myInt = {1, 3, 2};
float[] myFloat = {.5, .4, .3};
```

After sort the values should be:

```
myInt:   {1, 2, 3}
myFloat: {.5, .3, .4}
```

Comment: can this be somehow useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556129/java-sort-one-array-based-on-values-of-another-array

Comment: No, it isn't. My problem is not the comparator (sorting with int comparison is just easy), but that the sort algorithm always swaps values in both arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but the general idea is to create a *third* array of indexes 0 to n (hopefully that's not too much memory). You then sort this array using a comparator that instead compares items based on the equivalent values in `myInt`. I think this is what @fantaghirocco was suggesting, and it'd look like this:

```
int[] myInt = {1, 3, 2};
float[] myFloat = {.5, .4, .3};

ArrayList<int> indexes = IntStream.range(0, myInt.length);
Collections.sort(indexes, Comparator.comparing(i -> myInt[i]));
```

The array `indexes` now contains all numbers from 0 to `myInt.length`, where each value is the index of a number from myInt/myFloat. Example:

```java
myFloat = [0.3, 0.1, 0.2];
indexes = [1, 2, 0]; // Equivalent to [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```

You can then create new sorted myInt/myFloat arrays based on these indexes, or use them to swap values in-place until myInt/myFloat are sorted. The new order would look like this:

```java
myIntSorted = [myInt[indexes[0]], myInt[indexes[1]], myInt[indexes[2]], ...];
```

Comment: You are right, sorry for my first (bad because wrong) comment. That is really a cool idea! I will have to calculate the memory, maybe I have luck. (Size of my arrays will be nearly 350.000.000 values. 8 byte for every pair and 4 byte for every index will be nearly 4 GB. That could be makeable with the remaining data.) Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, not enough memory for the third array. :-( Maybe I have to write the sorting algorithm for my own...

Comment: @Christian Note that swapping values means loading them into cache first, so swapping values in two arrays at the same time will hurt your cache hits and therefore sorting speed. I wouldn't be surprised if it ends only marginally faster than sorting the two arrays separately.

Comment: Sorting such big arrays is no kind of cache problem, the cache is too small for just a single array. But there is another problem in your idea: A sorting algorithm will compare and swap array elements multiple times, so using the original array for the comparator will lead in sort mistakes.